# How to setup CICD for Azure Databricks using Azure DevOPS?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-databricks, cicd, azure-deployment

My requirement is I have one Dev Databricks Instance in which all the dev code is present and this dev code is integrated with Azure REPOS Git (Azure DevOPS).

I have another Databricks instance Prod, I want to push all the dev code from dev Databricks instance to Prod Databricks instance and I want to achieve this using Azure Devops CICD Pipeline.

How to achieve this ?

There is this URL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/ci-cd/ci-cd-azure-devops for setting up CICD for Databricks but I found this is very complex and lot of steps involved.

Can anyone help me to achieve this in simple steps rather than as mentioned in above URL.
Kindly Help.

Comment: is your code in notebooks? or it's Python packaged as wheel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed this article to resolve.

https://purple.telstra.com/blog/how-to-setup-ci-cd-for-databricks-on-azure-devops

Note : Install necessary extensions from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com mentioned in this article.

Comment: Hi thanks for your sharing, could you mark your answer to benefit more users?

Answer (score 0):

I think as a simple deployment, you may:

1. Create CI buid pipeline to copy and publish your databricks folder, like:

   ```
   - task: CopyFiles@2
     displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
     inputs:
       SourceFolder: adb
       TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'    

   - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
     displayName: 'Publish Artifact: ADB'
     inputs:
       ArtifactName: ADB
   ```
2. Then create a release pipeline to deploy your folder. To deploy, you may use this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DataThirstLtd.databricksDeployScriptsTasks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full official doc process for the [CI/CI integration from Azure DevOps to Azure Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/ci-cd/ci-cd-azure-devops).

> **Continuous integration:**
>
> ***1.Code***
>
> a.Develop code and unit tests in an Azure Databricks notebook or
> using an external IDE.
>
> b.Manually run tests.
>
> c.Commit code and tests to a git branch.
>
> ***2.Build***
>
> a.Gather new and updated code and tests.
>
> b.Run automated tests.
>
> c.Build libraries and non-notebook Apache Spark code.
>
> ***3.Release:*** Generate a release artifact.
>
> **Continuous delivery:**
>
> ***1.Deploy***
>
> a.Deploy notebooks.
>
> b.Deploy libraries.
>
> ***2.Test:*** Run automated tests and report results.
>
> ***3.Operate:*** Programmatically schedule data engineering, analytics, and machine learning workflows.